# Unable to create a new column in dataframe based on another column R Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, rstudio-server

I have a dataframe where I'm creating new columns on top of it. Some of those are dependent on a existing column. If I create a new column based on an existing column without any binary operation, it works fine. But if I try creating a new column based on some binary operation on an existing column, I get an error. Here's my code :

```
d9 = data1 //data1 is a dataframe
    d9['A/B/C'] <- numeric()
    d9['A'] <- d9$INTERVAL
    d9['B'] <-  0.75*d9$INTERVAL
    d9['C'] <- 1
```

Here's the error :

Error in 0.75 * d9$INTERVAL : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I have tried this as well :

```
d9['B'] <-  as.numeric(0.75*d9$INTERVAL)
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: What is `d9$INTERVAL` ? From the error it seems, it is not numeric. It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: It's a column based on which two of the new columns are created. Assume INTERVAL is the only column in the dataframe and the new columns are created on top of it. e.g.

INTERVAL = 10  A/B/C = 2  A = 10 , B = 7.5, C =1
INTERVAL = 20  A/B/C = 4  A = 20 , B = 15, C =1
INTERVAL = 40  A/B/C = 6  A = 40 , B = 30,  C =1

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have only one column.

`R` coerces to the lowest possible dimension.

So add `drop=FALSE` (default is `drop=TRUE`) and it works.

The other way round: If you have at least two columns then your code will work also without `drop=FALSE`:

Here is a example with `mtcars` dataset

```
d9 <- mtcars[,1, drop=FALSE]
d9
new_cols <-  c("A", "B", "C")
d9[new_cols] <- NA
d9

d9["A"] <- d9$mpg
d9["B"] <- d9$mpg*0.75
d9["C"] <- 1
d9
```

output:

```
                     mpg    A      B C
Mazda RX4           21.0 21.0 15.750 1
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 21.0 15.750 1
Datsun 710          22.8 22.8 17.100 1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 21.4 16.050 1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7 18.7 14.025 1
Valiant             18.1 18.1 13.575 1
Duster 360          14.3 14.3 10.725 1
Merc 240D           24.4 24.4 18.300 1
Merc 230            22.8 22.8 17.100 1
Merc 280            19.2 19.2 14.400 1
Merc 280C           17.8 17.8 13.350 1
....
```